# How to make selected triggered divs maintain visibility until other divs are hovered over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make selected `divs` (paired with`.stayhovered`) that were triggered upon hovering over a `div` maintain visible until the person hover overs a different `div`?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/nbsornn9/) here.

Thank you in advance!

**HTML**

```
<div class="show" id="subject01">
    <h1>Subject 01</h1>
    <div class="targetDiv info01">
        <div class="topleft stayhovered">
            <b>Subject 01, topleft<br/><u>Maintain hover</u> until subject02 is hovered</b></div>
        <div class="topright">
            Subject 01, topright<br/>Fadeout when cursor hovers out</div>
        <div class="bottomleft stayhovered">
           <b>Subject 01, bottomleft<br/><u>Maintain hover</u> until subject02 is hovered</b></div>
        <div class="bottomright">
            Subject 01, bottomright<br/>Fadeout when cursor hovers out</div>
    </div> <!-- END | 01 target -->
</div> <!-- END | 01 show -->


<div class="show" id="subject02">
    <h1>Subject 02</h1>
    <div class="targetDiv info02">
        <div class="topleft">
             Subject 02, topleft<br/>Fadeout when cursor hovers out</div>
        <div class="topright stayhovered">
            <b>Subject 02, topright<br/><u>Maintain hover</u> until subject01 is hovered</b></div>
        <div class="bottomleft">
            Subject 02, bottomleft<br/>Fadeout when cursor hovers out</div>
        <div class="bottomright stayhovered">
            <b>Subject 02, bottomright<br/><u>Maintain hover</u> until subject01 is hovered</b></div>
    </div> <!-- END | 02 target -->
</div> <!-- END | 02 show -->
```

**CSS**

```
/* hoverover text placement */

body {
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.topleft, .topright, .bottomleft, .bottomright {
    position: fixed;
}

.topleft {
    top:2%;
    left:2%;
    }

.topright {
    top:2%;
    right:2%;
    }

.bottomleft {
    bottom:2%;
    left:2%;
    }

.bottomright {
    bottom:2%;
    right:2%;
    }


/* Feature Typography */
 .featuretitle, .featureinfo, .rotate {

}
.featuretitle {

}
.featureinfo {

}
/* FEATURE DETAIL */
 .featuredetail {
    font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 18px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 50%
}

/* Subjects */

 #subject01 {
    left: 30%;
    top: 30%;
    position: fixed;
    color: #FE5722;
}

#subject02 {
    right: 30%;
    bottom: 30%;
    position: fixed;
    color: #3F51B5;
}

/* Feature */
 .feature-img-wrap {
    display:block;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.targetDiv {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 250ms linear;
    transition: all 250ms linear;
}
.show:hover .targetDiv {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity:1;
}
.show:hover .stayhovered {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: This has been answered loads of times on here, But do you want it with css or jquery

Comment: Hi @Billy I think I would prefer css only—is that possible?

Comment: @kenhimself - I don't think its possible with CSS alone. You'll need JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: yes, it is ,add a tabindex to the div and a focus psuedo selector to display block. code snippet in short while

Comment: @Billy I'm not too familiar with tabindex, would you mind demonstrating here: http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/nbsornn9/

Comment: Working on it now as I'm not too familiar with it my self but I know it's there, My short while above may be a bit longer. I'll get back to you when it's ready

Comment: Thank you @Billy looking forward to hearing back :)

Comment: Lost my internet connection last night, Carried on trying then and this morning. The tabindex is for clicking, not hovering, So no matter what I tried couldn't get it to work. Sorry for leading you up the garden path. Opened my mouth before knowing for sure ...again

Comment: @Billy -- no worries! I did do some research on it and it seems really cool! I'll definitely play around with it for a different project. If anything you introduced me to something cool :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was quite the challenge, but I think I've got it.

Here's the Fiddle:  **http://jsfiddle.net/n810v1se/**

... and the **Snippet**:

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.topleft {
  top:2%;
  left:2%;
}

.topright {
  top:2%;
  right:2%;
}

.bottomleft {
  bottom:2%;
  left:2%;
}

.bottomright {
  bottom:2%;
  right:2%;
}


/* Subjects */

#subject01 {
  left: 30%;
  top: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  color: #FE5722;
}

#subject02 {
  right: 30%;
  bottom: 30%;
  position: fixed;
  color: #3F51B5;
}

.targetDiv {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 250ms linear;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}

.topleft, .topright, .bottomleft, .bottomright {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 250ms linear;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}

.stayhovered {
  opacity: 1;
}

h1:hover ~ div .topleft,
h1:hover ~ div .topright,
h1:hover ~ div .bottomleft,
h1:hover ~ div .bottomright
{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.show:hover .targetDiv {
  visibility: visible;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: -1;
}

.show:hover {
  z-index: 0;
}

.show {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="show" id="subject01">
    <h1>Subject 01</h1>
    <div class="targetDiv info01">
        <div class="topleft stayhovered">
            <b>Subject 01, topleft<br/><u>Maintain hover</u> until subject02 is hovered</b></div>
        <div class="topright">
            Subject 01, topright<br/>Fadeout when cursor hovers out</div>
        <div class="bottomleft stayhovered">
           <b>Subject 01, bottomleft<br/><u>Maintain hover</u> until subject02 is hovered</b></div>
        <div class="bottomright">
            Subject 01, bottomright<br/>Fadeout when cursor hovers out</div>
    </div> <!-- END | 01 target -->
</div> <!-- END | 01 show -->


<div class="show" id="subject02">
    <h1>Subject 02</h1>
    <div class="targetDiv info02">
        <div class="topleft">
             Subject 02, topleft<br/>Fadeout when cursor hovers out</div>
        <div class="topright stayhovered">
            <b>Subject 02, topright<br/><u>Maintain hover</u> until subject01 is hovered</b></div>
        <div class="bottomleft">
            Subject 02, bottomleft<br/>Fadeout when cursor hovers out</div>
        <div class="bottomright stayhovered">
            <b>Subject 02, bottomright<br/><u>Maintain hover</u> until subject01 is hovered</b></div>
    </div> <!-- END | 02 target -->
</div> <!-- END | 02 show -->
```

**How it works**

The corner elements are within `targetDiv`, which is hidden by default.  It's easy enough to display `targetDiv` when hovering over its parent, the `show` class element:

```
.show:hover .targetDiv {visibility: visible;}
```

Even though the content within the `show`-class elements hits every corner of the viewport, the actual width and height of these elements is the width and height of the `h1` elements within them.  Why?  Because their corner elements have fixed positioning.  (To see this, add a border to the `show` class.)

This means that only the `h1` elements within `show` will respond to a `hover` event.

When the mouse leaves a `h1` element, the `hover` event is canceled, causing `targetDiv` to disappear.  However, we want `targetDiv` to stay visible until the *other* `h1` element is hovered.

We accomplish this by making `targetDiv` take up the whole screen when `show` is hovered:

```
.show:hover .targetDiv {
  ...
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

(`targetDiv` already has 100% width, so that's not needed here.)

Now when `show` is hovered, its `targetDiv` child takes up the entire viewport, causing it to stay hovered.

This works well when moving from `subject01` to `subject02`.  But now it's impossible to move from `subject02` from `subject01`.  Why?  Because when the `subject02`'s `show` parent is hovered, its content takes up the entire viewport.  Since `subject02` was declared *after* `subject01`, its parent is essentially *on top of* `subject01`, making it impossible for `subject01` to receive any mouse events.

The solution?  Give the `show` class a default z-index of 1.  When it's hovered, change its z-index to 0.  That way, it's always behind the other `show`-class element:

```
.show {z-index: 1;}
.show:hover {z-index: 0;}
```

Now to the challenge of keeping the `stayhovered` elements visible while the other corner elements are not.  We do this by adding `opacity:1` to `stayhovered`'s default style, and changing the corner elements to `opacity:1` only when their previous `h1` sibling is hovered:

```
.stayhovered {opacity: 1;}

h1:hover ~ div .topleft,h1:hover ~ div .topright,
h1:hover ~ div .bottomleft,h1:hover ~ div .bottomright {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

This seems all well and good.  *However*, now that `targetDiv` takes up the entire viewport, and it has fixed positioning, it essentially covers the `h1` element, making it impossible for the `h1` to receive a hover event!

The solution?  Add a negative `z-index` to `targetDiv`:

```
.show:hover .targetDiv {
  ...
  z-index: -1;
}
```

And that's the final piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Hi Rick, thank you for this, however, it seems that the divs that are not paired up with "stayhovered" continue to stay hovered when the mouse hovers out of the subject 01 / subject 02 text. any idea how this can be fixed? I would ideally like only the divs paired with "stayhovered" maintain active...

Comment: Aah, sorry I misunderstood.  I'll work on it when I have time.

Comment: looking fantastic @Rick Hitchcock -- but when the cursor hovers over the text again, the normal texts don't show up -- anyway it can perhaps reset?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean(?)

Comment: Woah, so strange, a moment ago it wasn't fully working but it's working just fine right now. must have been a glitch or something. thank you for your help :)

Comment: Whew.  The negative z-index was the last piece of the puzzle, and I was shocked that it actually works cross-browser.  At first glance, I thought it might be impossible to do without JavaScript.

Comment: You're a wizard @Rick Hitchcock! Ain't no CSS can't mess with a wizard's code.

Comment: Nice one, Been working on this for hours with @keyframes, transitions of 99999s all sorts, knew it could be done just didn't know how. Thought I'd check back here and you done it. +1

Comment: @Billy and kenhimself:  Thanks, friends!  Because the solution was non-trivial, (and because I don't want to forget how I did it), I've updated my answer with *How it works*.

Comment: I tried to add another +1 for the explaination but couldn't, so got another of your answers and +1'ed it.Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can add this javascript/jquery code without altering your css:

jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/j9vtjk6j/1/

```
 //on hover function for #subject01 function
$("#subject01").hover(function(){

    //make the .targetDiv visible
    $(this).find(".targetDiv").css("visibility","visible");

     //make this .targetDiv visible    
    $(this).find(".targetDiv").css("opacity",1);

    //make the #subject02 .targetDiv invisible
    $("#subject02 .targetDiv").css("opacity",0);





});

//#subject02 hover function
$("#subject02").hover(function(){

    //make the .targetDiv visible
    $(this).find(".targetDiv").css("visibility","visible");    

    //make this .targetDiv visible
    $(this).find(".targetDiv").css("opacity",1);

    //make the #subject01 .targetDiv visible
    $("#subject01 .targetDiv").css("opacity",0);





});
```

Comment: Hi Larry, thank you for the code but I think you misunderstood. I would only like the divs paired with ".stayhovered" maintain visibility and have everything else fade away after the mouse moves away. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will make some changes and let you know.

Comment: No worries! We solved this one, but please feel free to work from the resolved solution by Rick Hitchcock :)

Comment: I see a solution was found.